# Get report of all site collections using SMAT tool

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I used SMAT tool to analyze the Farm. I noticed that it creates a file called PublishingSites-detail.csv which contains the list of all publishing site collection and its subsites

Is there a way to get the same report done for all the site collections in the Farm?

Answer (score 2):

Do you simply want to have a list to show all the site collections with subsites? If so, a PowerShell script will be enough. Like this one:https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/02/sharepoint-site-collections-subsites-report.html

Comment: Thank you Jerry, I need some details that are available in the SMAT analysis report like  Hits, Distinct Users Count, Total Item Count, number of subsites, Site Admins etc.
I have asked another question on getting them using PowerShell script here, feel free to check that out
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/288619/

Answer (score 2):

Besides the mentioned references by Jerry, I have also written my own PowerShell script to [get the count and size of all site collection and subsites in your farm](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/all-site-collections-and-subsites-per-farm/) with a warning message based on the limitation!

[image]
[image]

Hope it also helps!

Comment: Thank you @Mohamed, I need Hits, Total Item count and Site Admins
These fields are available in the SMAT report, is it possible to get these with PowerShell?