# Get LastModifiedDate, Owner, Hits, Distinct Users, Site Size, Total Item Count of all Site collections in a Farm using Powershell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell

I am trying to get a report of all the site collections in a SP 2013 Farm

I am using the below command

```
Get-SPSite -Limit 10 | select url,LastContentModifiedDate,Owner, @{label="Size in MB";Expression={$_.usage.storage/1MB}} | Format-Table
```

This gives url,LastContentModifiedDate,Owner and size, is there a way to get the count of distinct users, Hits, Number of subsites and Total items count with Powershell?

I am ok with any output format, csv/table or any other format

Answer (score 1):

Still you can use PowerShell script to do so. You can try this one:https://github.com/chrisdee/Scripts/blob/master/PowerShell/Working/SharePoint/SharePoint2013/SP2013GetWebAnalyticsReport.ps1

And if PowerShell is not your only option, in fact we can get such usage data directly through UI. The popularity trends and usage reports are available in site settings. Check this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/view-usage-reports